# How to choose optimal Point in Time for Elasticsearch Pagination with search_after?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have large datasets, for which I am trying to perform the pagination,
while reading the documentation I came across the **PIT(Point-In-Time)** concepts, which will help to get the consistent results.

I am using below API to open PIT, **after 1m, it will be closed**.

```
POST /order/_pit?keep_alive=1m
```

Questions is: How to come up with the best **PIT** time(ex:1m,5m), so that my search request will be more performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html#point-in-time-keep-alive):

> The keep_alive parameter, which is passed to a open point in time request and search request, **extends the time** to live of the corresponding point in time. The value (e.g. 1m, see Time units) **does not need to be long enough to process all data** — it just needs to be **long enough for the next request**.

Comment: Thanks! so does it mean, if I have PIT=1m, for every search request, the timer will reset itself?

Comment: Yes, that's what it says and when you're done you can [close it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html#close-point-in-time-api) explicitly if you don't want it to stay open for one more minute (best practice).